# In Ruby, why does nil[1]=1 evaluate to nil?

Tags: ruby, null, ruby-2.3

For example:

```
nil[1]     #=> NoMethodError
nil[1]=1   #=> nil
```

It's not just syntax, as it happens with variables too:

```
a = nil
a[1]       #=> NoMethodError
a[1]=1     #=> nil
```

Oddly:

```
nil.method(:[]=)   #=> NameError
[].method(:[]=)    #=> #<Method...>
```

Ruby 2.3.0p0

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ruby 2.2.4. Maybe a new feature or a bug in your version?

Comment: Weird... Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I can only reproduce this in Ruby 2.3.0 and I'm going to presume it's a bug. It might be worth checking the [bug tracker for this issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org).

Comment: Probably it is fixed already. Cannot be reproduced on ruby 2.3.0p71 (2016-03-30 revision 54426).

Comment: I believe the fix was reported [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11976) ("unexpected safe call"). larsch, how did you happen to stumble onto that? Everyone, raises your glasses! It's not everyday that a suspected bug turns out to actually be a bug.

Comment: This is why we avoid the *latest* version

Comment: I simple had an instance variable `@idx = Hash.new` that I was trying to use as `@index[key] = value`. The unittest was failing in strange ways because the assignment didn't fail on the `nil` value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Do you want to post that info as an answer so I can mark [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894267/what-is-the-purpose-of-method-on-nil) as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks, @Jordan, but I'd prefer to leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Some random findings: *[only in Ruby 2.3.0p0]*

The method doesn't seem to exist:

```
nil.method(:[]=)      #=> NameError: undefined method `[]='
nil.respond_to?(:[]=) #=> false
```

And you can't invoke it using `send`:

```
nil.send(:[]=)        #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]='
```

Ruby evaluates neither the right hand side, nor the argument, i.e.

```
nil[foo]=bar
```

doesn't raise a `NameError`, although `foo` and `bar` are undefined.

The expression seems to be equivalent to `nil`:

```
$ ruby --dump=insns -e 'nil[foo]=bar'
== disasm: #<ISeq:<main>@-e>============================================
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putnil
0003 leave

$ ruby --dump=insns -e 'nil'
== disasm: #<ISeq:<main>@-e>============================================
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putnil
0003 leave
```