# What is the purpose of []= method on nil

Tags: ruby

Since ruby 2.3.0, you can call `[]=` method on `nil`. I don't understand the purpose of this method.

For instance:

```
nil[1] = 1
# or
nil['foo'] = 'bar'
```

but `[]` method does not exist:

```
nil[1]
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The ruby [2.3.0 changelog](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/) does not mention that changes, although it seems close to the safe navigation operator.

What is the purpose of this operator?

Comment: Which build of Ruby do you run? What OS do you use? How did you install Ruby 2.3.0? Is it a fresh installation or do you have additional gems installed?

Answer (score 0):

That method [isn't documented in Ruby `2.3.0`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html) and I cannot reproduce this behavior in Ruby `2.3.1` (both examples raise `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass`).

Furthermore I reinstalled `2.3.0` and was only partly able to reproduce your examples:

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.0
Downloading ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.0...
Installed ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/spickermann/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0

$ rbenv shell 2.3.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]

$ irb
irb   > RUBY_VERSION
irb  => "2.3.0"
irb   > nil[1] = 1
irb  => nil
irb   > nil['foo'] = 'bar'
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
  from (irb):3
  from /Users/spickermann/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

It seems like `NilClass#[]=` doesn't work properly in Ruby `2.3.0`. Since it was completely removed in `2.3.1`, I guess that this method or this behavior was added by accident.

**Update**: Cary Swoveland pointed out in a [comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829168/in-ruby-why-does-nil1-1-evaluate-to-nil#comment61230637_36829168) that this behavior was a bug and was fixed in later versions (see: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11976).

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be actually a bug in 2.3.0 - https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11976

It does not evaluate the arguments:

```
nil[undefined_index_variable] = raise "Fooo!" # => nil
```